# How to enable Office365 authentication in ASP.NET MVC project set with individual accounts?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, office365, owin

I am working on this `ASP.NET MVC` project where I am trying to have both local and Office365 logins. This will enable users to create both local account, and use their Office365 account to login.

I looked up online, and here is what I have found so far:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "",
    Authority = "",
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
}
```

To enable this, I need to have `using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;` imported. However, I seem to be missing something somewhere.